# Python 2.7: Give input to python scripted EXE file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have written a simple program in python which takes input value and display result accordingly.

**Program**: Test.py

```
a=raw_input('Enter value1:')
b=raw_input('Enter value2:')
#Do some work here based on passed inputs
```

I have to run the program in the different system where there will not be python installed. So I created `Test.exe` file using `pyinstaller`.

Now when I run `.exe` it's getting closed within seconds.

**Question**: How can I give a message `Enter value1:` to user to put some input values by running `.exe` file?

Comment: `c:\python27\python -m pyinstaller --onefile  test.py` ....  at a guess you installed pyinstaller for python3 inadvertently ...

Comment: Please give the reason for down vote.

Comment: Can you tell us how did you created test.exe using pyinstaller?

Comment: @Azhy, I new to python, so I just followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=63&v=lOIJIk_maO4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**make.bat**

```
rem CREATE our test.py
echo a=raw_input('Enter value1:') > test.py
echo b=raw_input('Enter value2:') >> test.py

rem Install Pyinstaller
c:\python27\python -m pip install pyinstaller -U
rem Build IT!!!!!
c:\python27\scripts\pyinstaller --onefile test.py
rem RUN IT!!!!
dist\test.exe
```